# I want to change font color with jquery based on condition after looping through json array

Tags: jquery

I am looping through a JSON array using .each() in Jquery and I want to change the font color to red if the value contains the word "CALL". I have followed several examples with no luck.

```
$(function () {
    var FetchMonUrl = '@Url.Action("FetchToday")';
    $.getJSON(FetchMonUrl, { MonID: ('@FetchDay') }, function (dataFetch) {
        $.each(dataFetch, function (key, value) {
            $('#TodayName').html(dataFetch);
            alert(this);
            if ($(this).is(':contains("CALL")')) {
                $(this).css('color', 'red');
            } 
        });           
    });
});
```

Comment: It's not clear that `this` is an element on the page, or a detached element.  As far as I can tell, `this` is the `window` there, or one of the objects in the `dataFetch`.

Comment: Also your repeated setting of the `#TodayName` html is a code smell

Comment: Also pointing out an inconsistency, your title says you want to do something after looping.  But you're not.  You're trying to do something while looping

Comment: Please provide an example of `dataFetch`. For example, if this is an array, then there are LOTS of parts of this that won't work.

Comment: I didn't answer.  I commented, seeking more information.  Also, when interacting within a community related to coding, you should always be open to questions pertaining to your logic and your approach.  It's not an attack.  It's intended to be though provoking and make you re-evaluate possible preconceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    var FetchMonUrl = '@Url.Action("FetchToday")';
    $.getJSON(FetchMonUrl, { MonID: ('@FetchDay') }, function (dataFetch) {
        $.map(dataFetch, function (value, key) {
            if (value.indexOf("CALL") >= 0) {
                value2 = value.fontcolor('#cd0000');
                dataFetch[key] = value2;                    
            } 
            $('#TodayName').html(dataFetch);

        });           
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect thew returning data is an Array, since you're looping it with `$.each()`. If so, consider the following.

```
$(function () {
  var FetchMonUrl = '@Url.Action("FetchToday")';
  $.getJSON(FetchMonUrl, { MonID: ('@FetchDay') }, function (dataFetch) {
    $('#TodayName').html(dataFetch.toString());
    $.each(dataFetch, function (key, value) {
      if (value.indexOf("CALL") >= 0) {
        $('#TodayName').css('color', 'red');
      } 
    });           
  });
});
```

If the data returned is not an Array, but is Text, I would just use `$.get()`.

The `:contains` is a pseudo selector for elements not data. It can't be used in the manner you tried to use it. `.indexOf()` will return the Index of the specific string in a string (or Array) or `-1` if not found.

Comment: This code changed ALL my values red, not just the values that contain "CALL".

Comment: @qpc4ever then you need to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example